# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream does not load stream

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I use stream reader to read sql data. Although resourceName is correct and the resource Build Action property is Embedded Resource it still throws following error on StreamReader:
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

```
        var namespace1 = typeof(Toolbox).Namespace;
        var name1 = name.Replace('\\', '.');
        string resourceName = $"{typeof(Toolbox).Namespace}.{name1}";
        //Innosys.Ap.GetCurrentTimeKey.sql
        using (Stream manifestResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
        )
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(manifestResourceStream))
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

**Following are my debugging results so far.**

1. namespace1 returns the correct name space used for the class from the project i.e. The class from which I call streamReader, resource file.
2. name1 returns resource file name with extension. ie. myquery.sql
3. resourcename which basically combines the path and the file name returns from my point of view the correct resouce address. i.e. myNamespace.myquery.sql

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: The names of resources are often not what you expect them to be. Use `GetManifestResourceNames()` to verify the actual name.

Comment: @LajosArpad on using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(manifestResourceStream))

Comment: @JeroenMostert I created a new variable as following and debugged it returns null.

Stream manfstrsrcstrm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

Comment: That's nice, but that's what your code already does. Verify that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` gives the assembly you expect, and that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` gives the resources you expect.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes it does. 
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returns assembly the right assembly.

Comment: Then resourceName is null. Which means that {typeof(Toolbox).Namespace}.{name1} must exist, but the value of that name is not initialized.